# Jquery cookie to run animation once only

Tags: jquery

Ok so i have a menu bar that toggles down from the top of the screen. I only want users to see this the first time they hit the site. How do i prevent it from playing on every subsequent page they go to?

**My jQuery:**

```
$(function() {

    $(".bar-top").delay(700).animate({
        marginTop: '0px'
    }, 750, 'swing');


    if ( $(".banner-title").css('display') == 'block' ) {
        $(".banner-title").delay(1500).addClass("fade");
        $(".fade").fadeIn("slow");
        $(".fade").hide();
    }

});
```

I've looked into setting a cookie, but as of yet nothings worked properly. Mainly because i'm not sure how to wrap this in a cookie if statement. The `banner-title` is just some text that fades in alongside the navigation.

I was thinking is there a way to maybe only run the code on the index page, and prevent it from running anywhere else? That might not be such a good solution though.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your users are not authenticated with your site, the only way to persist state between page requests is to set a cookie.

There's a great JavaScript API for cookie management which you should check out - https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

When a user hits your site, you can check your cookie to see if they've been there before. If they haven't then display your animation and set the cookie. If they have then don't run the animation.

From a glance at the `js-cookie` docs, you can set a cookie for 7 days like so:

```
Cookies.set('visited', 'value', { expires: 7 });
```

So your code might look like:

```
// Make sure DOM has fully loaded before running code
$(function(){
    if( ! Cookies.get('visited')){
        // Your code here
        Cookies.set('visited', 'yes', { expires: 7 });
    }
});
```

**Edit to answer other part of your question (thanks for the reminder Max Allen!)**

To only run code on certain pages I'd recommend having IDs (and classes if you like) on the body tag of the page. e.g.

```
if ($('body#index').length){
    // Code to only run on index page
}
```

Comment: I get an error when i try implement this. I think it's because i've already got an 'if' statement for my code. Would i need to turn it into a variable or something?

Answer (score 0):

Well, @Tim Fletcher answered a bit of your question.

> I was thinking is there a way to maybe only run the code on the index page, and prevent it from running anywhere else? That might not be such a good solution though.

Well there might be one solution:

```
if(window.location.pathname == '/index.html'){
//Your code
}
```

But I will not say how good or bad this is. But it may work.